# Scipy griddata interpolating only from boundary information

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using griddata from Scipy in Python 2.7 to interpolate from some coarse sampling data to make a contour plot.  In short, I have a pond with a certain outline and depth/pH/temperature measurements throughout the pond.  At the boundaries, I set the depth = 0 and pH/temperature to the same as the nearest neighbor sample point inside of the pond.

However, after running the script and messing around with the input data, it has become apparent that griddata is simply taking the data from the exterior of the area that I'm trying to interpolate in and simply deriving an interpolant from that.  I can enter into whatever data I want in the interior, and it will not matter at all to the result.

I've created the following, simplified example that appears to display the same behavior.  In it, I specify a 5x5 grid of manufactured data, which is all zero except for the dead center, which is large.  I then try to interpolate data on a grid that is 4 times as dense, thinking that I should see some sort of a spike in the middle.  Instead, all values come out as the same thing: zero.  This code is given below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata as grid_interp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

########################################################################

# create input grid
input_grid = np.zeros([25,2])
k=0
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        input_grid[k,0] = i
        input_grid[k,1] = j
        k = k + 1

# put a value in the center of the grid
input_values = np.zeros([25,1])
input_values[12] = 1000000.0

# create grid to interpolate onto
target_grid = np.ones([100,100,2])
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        target_grid[i,j,0] = i/100*5
        target_grid[i,j,1] = i/100*5

# perform interpolation
data_out = grid_interp(input_grid,input_values,target_grid[:,:,:],method='cubic',fill_value=-99)

# format for contourf
plot_array = np.zeros([100,100])
plot_array[:,:] = data_out[:,:,0]

# plot
plt.contourf(target_grid[:,:,0],target_grid[:,:,1],plot_array)
```

So...at this point, I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do I upload the input files, or should I just append data to the question?

Comment: OK -- updated.  Thanks!

Comment: When I print the results of data_out.max() at runtime (with the code I posted) it returns 0 for me.

Comment: I am running SciPy 0.19.0...and it is on Windows 10.  Any chance there's an easy way to update?

Comment: Using `plt.contourf(plot_array); plt.axis('square');` for the last line gives you what you expect? you could include a small sample (10-15 points) of your data in the question, something we can copy and paste. It seems that the problem is how the 'pond' data are transformed to be supplied to `griddata`

Comment: @xdze2 - it does not give me what I expect because the output from griddata is uniformly zero.  I'm in the middle updating my Anaconda distribution now, however, which appears to have a role in this problem.

Comment: @user6655984 - OK, I just updated scipy and numpy, which brings me to scipy 1.1.0 and numpy 1.15.0.  Again, I can run the code I pasted in the question and the maximum value of data_out is zero.

Comment: I (belatedly) see it's Python 2.7, so `i/100` is 0 and the target grid is not what you wanted it to be.

Comment: General advice: when a function acts weird, insert `print` not only for its output, but also for its input.

Comment: Ah -- yep, that's it.  Converted i to a float and data_out.max() returns 1000000.0.  Changing a couple of other terms to make sure everything falls into the interpolation domain, and I get exactly the output that I'm looking for.  Modifying the input to contourf so that I'm not trying to broadcast from target_grid into the function gives me the contour plot that I want as well.  Time to try and replicate this in my other code.  Thanks!